# Rails: more convenient hash dumps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When things went wrong, Rails echoes a dump of given params, it looks like this:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "filter"=>{"title"=>"1",
 "address"=>"2",
 "city"=>{"title"=>"3"},
 "people"=>{"name"=>"4",
 "surname"=>"5",
 "patronymic"=>"6",
 "emails"=>{"email"=>"7"}},
 "emails"=>{"email"=>"8"}},
 "sort"=>{"0"=>{"field"=>"",
 "dir"=>"asc"},
 "1"=>{"field"=>"",
 "dir"=>"asc"}},
 "commit"=>"Show"}
```

But it actually would be much more useful if looks like this:

```
{
  "utf8" => "✓",
  "filter" => {
    "title" => "1",
    "address" => "2",
    "city" => {
      "title" => "3"
    },
    "people" => {
      "name" => "4",
      "surname" => "5",
      "patronymic" => "6",
      "emails" => {
        "email" => "7"
      }
    },
    "emails" => {
      "email" => "8"
    }
  },
  "sort" => {
    "0" => {
      "field" => "",
      "dir" => "asc"
    },
    "1" => {
      "field" => "",
      "dir" => "asc"
    }
  },
  "commit" => "Show"
}
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla Ruby the nicest way is to turn the hash to JSON:

```
JSON::pretty_generate(hash_here, :allow_nan => true, :max_nesting => false)
```

This outputs a prettified JSON version of your object (array, hash or whatever). It won´t be pure ruby but this comes right at the base library so there is no need to install anything.

Comment: But, should I modify/recompile rails itself to change its way to print hash dumps when some error happened?